# ADB losing connection when phone screen turns off

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm using ADB WiFi. Everything is working fine, except that when my android screen turns off I need to reconnect using "adb connect IP_ADRESS:5555". Is there any solution for this?

Comment: WiFi is getting OFF in sleep mode. You can change WiFi sleep policy from WiFi Advance Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to check "Settings" -> "Wi-Fi" -> "Advanced" (in 3-dot menu) -> "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep". You may also try to turn off the "Wi-Fi optimization" in the same menu. Sometimes Wi-Fi drivers can have problems with power saving mode.

Comment: Keep Wi-Fi Option is correct and there isnt Wi-Fi Optimization option here.

Answer (score 3):

I tried every possible solution noting works for me then I changed some of my phone settings and it works :-)

1. Go to the developer option and make sure USB debugging is ON.
2. Scroll down and find "Select USB configuration" and set Charging
3. Find "Default USB Configration" and set File Transfer

And this works for me

Comment: when i first saw this i could not believe that this will work, but it works thanks man

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the rom in some kinds of android devices, apparently. This fixed it for me:

Link: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/1382

Here's what you have to do:
Go to Usb preferences in developer options, and change it from "data transfer" or anything else to "no data transfer".

Answer (score 0):

Using **Android 12**, I encountered the same issue, I searched for wifi sleep management without success.
So I set the app's sleep management **individually** using the steps below :

- I displayed the list of all apps running (display bottom square button of Android)
- I long-pressed the debugged app, and the "App Info" is opened.
- Finally I changed "Battery Saver" to "No restrictions".

It works: I keep the device connection in my IDE!